# jqmodal show before selecting trigger

Tags: jquery, jqmodal

I'm trying to show a pop-up when someone selects an option from the select. But the pop-up appears when you click the select and not after you select an option.

My code

```
<select id='town' name='town'>
<option value=''>Dans quelle ville?</option>
<option value='1'>Paris</option>
<option value='2'>Roma</option>
<option value='3'>Barcelona</option>
</select>
<script>
$().ready(function() {
$('#popup').jqm({trigger: $('#town').change()});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you're triggering the modal whenever the select element (#town) is clicked. That's what trigger is for (a shortcut to bind click events to opening modals).

In this case; you'll manually You want to show the modal when the select element changes. To do so the script should look like:

```
<script>
$().ready(function() {
  $('#popup').jqm();
  $('#town').change(function(){ $('#popup').jqmShow(); });
});
</script>
```